# DataTable.WriteXML and Child Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, writexml

I've got the following snippet of code:

```
        var dataSet = new DataSet("Data");
        var table = GetCustomerTable();
        var orgTable = GetOrganizationTable();
        dataSet.Tables.Add(table);
        dataSet.Tables.Add(orgTable);
        var relation = new DataRelation("CustomerMembership", dataSet.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerId"], dataSet.Tables["Organizations"].Columns["CustomerId"])
                        {Nested = true};
        dataSet.Relations.Add(relation);
        dataSet.WriteXml(@"C:\MyFeed.xml");
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
<Customers>
    <CustomerId>272408857</CustomerId>
    <snip>
    <Organizations>
      <OrganizationName>Org1</OrganizationName>
    </Organizations>
    <Organizations>
      <OrganizationName>Org2</OrganizationName>
    </Organizations>
  </Customers>
```

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
<Customers>
    <CustomerId>272408857</CustomerId>
    <snip>
    <Organizations>
      <OrganizationName>Org1</OrganizationName>
      <OrganizationName>Org2</OrganizationName>
    </Organizations>
  </Customers>
```

Any ideas on how I can get `OrganizationName` nested inside of one `Organization` node; instead of having 2 nodes with one value each?

Comment: You can probably use attributes like `<OrganizationName name="Org1"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataColumn dc = orgTable.Columns["OrganizationName"];
dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
```

Adding this to your code will output the following:

```
<Customers>
    <CustomerId>272408857</CustomerId>
    <snip>
    <Organizations OrganizationName = "Org1"/>
    <Organizations OrganizationName = "Org2"/>
</Customers>
```

It is not exactly what you need, but I think you cannot collect the child nodes of a join in a table-tag with .net tools. You will probably have to transform the xml by yourself.

You could also rename your DataTable to "Organization" such that you will have a list of `Organization` Elements (still lacking a parent `Organizations` element though).

What do you think?

Comment: Yeah; I wasn't able to find a way to get this with the WriteXml method.  I ended up using a little Linq to XML to get it the way I wanted.